# Install pecl_http fail

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl

I use Ubuntu 14

And when I execute the following command:

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

I have the following error :

```
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading pecl_http-2.4.3.tgz ...

Starting to download pecl_http-2.4.3.tgz (188,540 bytes)
.........................................done: 188,540 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/pecl_http-2.4.3.tgz"
Download of "pecl/pecl_http" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/pecl_http"
downloading raphf-1.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download raphf-1.0.4.tgz (7,232 bytes)
...done: 7,232 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/raphf-1.0.4.tgz"
Download of "pecl/raphf" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/raphf"
downloading propro-1.0.0.tgz ...
Starting to download propro-1.0.0.tgz (6,217 bytes)
...done: 6,217 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/propro-1.0.0.tgz"
Download of "pecl/propro" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/propro"
Download failed
install failed
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Run sudo pecl channel-update as per the warning and the package will extract correctly

Comment: But when I execute : sudo pecl channel-update
I have the following error : Cannot open pecl_http

Comment: ok do the following as one command (Stackoverflow formatting causing problems!)

sudo pecl channel-update; sudo pecl install pecl_http

Comment: Sorry, I execute the command but I still have the same error

Comment: I execute also : sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net , and I have the response :
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Update of Channel "pecl.php.net" succeeded,  but after when I execute sudo pecl install pecl_http I have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this problem.
My SE Ubuntu was on 32 bits.
So I passed on a 64-bit OS